# python multiply your last answer by a constant

Tags: python

so I'm trying to display salary with annual % increase for certain amount of years

```
print('Enter the strting salary: ', end ='')
SALARY = float(input())
print('Enter the annual % increase: ', end ='')
ANNUAL_INCREASE = float(input())

calculation1 = ANNUAL_INCREASE / 100
calculation2 = calculation1 * SALARY
calculation3 = calculation2 + SALARY



Yearloops = int(input('Enter number of years: '))

for x in range(Yearloops):
    print(x + 1, calculation3 )
```

This is my output so far by entering 25000 as salary, 3 as % increase and 5 for years.

```
1 25750.0
2 25750.0
3 25750.0
4 25750.0
5 25750.0
```

I need to multiply the last answer again by the % increase. Should be like this

```
1 25000.00 
2 25750.00 
3 26522.50
4 27318.17 
5 28137.72
```

Can someone show me how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your calculations inside your for loop so that it occurs every year instead of just once

```
salary = float(input('enter starting salary: '))
annual_increase = float(input('enter the annual % increase: '))
years = int(input('enter number of years: '))

for x in range(years):
    print(x + 1, salary)

    increase = (annual_increase/100) * salary
    salary += increase
```

Entering 25000, 3%, and 5 years outputs

```
1 25000.0
2 25750.0
3 26522.5
4 27318.175
5 28137.72025
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting a bit your version of the code:

```
print('Enter the strting salary: ', end ='')
SALARY = float(input())
print('Enter the annual % increase: ', end ='')
ANNUAL_INCREASE = float(input())

Yearloops = int(input('Enter number of years: '))

value = SALARY
for x in range(Yearloops):
    print('{} {:.2f}'.format(x + 1, value))
    value = value * (1 + ANNUAL_INCREASE/100)
```

This produces the following output with the test case 25000, 3, 5:

```
Enter the strting salary: 25000
Enter the annual % increase: 3
Enter number of years: 5
1 25000.00
2 25750.00
3 26522.50
4 27318.17
5 28137.72
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you are looking for:

```
print('Enter the strting salary: ', end ='')
SALARY = float(input())
print('Enter the annual % increase: ', end ='')
ANNUAL_INCREASE = float(input())

calculation1 = ANNUAL_INCREASE / 100

Yearloops = int(input('Enter number of years: '))

newsalary = SALARY
print(1, newsalary )
for x in range(1,Yearloops):
    newsalary = newsalary*(1+calculation1)
    print(x + 1, newsalary )
```

I printed the first year outside the loop since we don't want to calculate an increase yet, according to your spec.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a pretty straightforward solution to your problem. For your knowledge: it is common to use `for _ in something` when you aren't actually going to use the item you're iterating over.

```
print('Enter the starting salary: ', end ='')
SALARY = float(input())
print('Enter the annual % increase: ', end ='')
ANNUAL_INCREASE = float(input())

Yearloops = int(input('Enter number of years: '))

for _ in range(Yearloops):
    print(SALARY)
    SALARY += (SALARY / 100) * ANNUAL_INCREASE
```